# Spacy - problem during the training of my model, it seems to block at epoch 0

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I am training my named entity recogniser but I have the impression that it blocks at epoch 0. I have already done several trainings and I have never had this problem. Does anyone have any tips? I am attaching a screenshot of my terminal. Many thanks!!

[image]

Comment: Don't paste screenshots of text, paste text as text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's likely you just have too much data and your training is slow.

How much data do you have? How much RAM? What does `spacy debug data` show?

Comment: Spacy debug data shows no error in this area. But I think I found the problem when I read your answer: I trained my recognizer on a corpus of tweets where no tweet is delimited so Spacy interprets it as a single document. Is this possible? Thanks you very much!

Comment: If you have no delimiters it certainly sounds possible you treated your entire corpus as one giant document, and I can imagine things choking while loading that. `debug data` should clarify that for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was the problem... :)